# VS Code: debugging of javascript. Different behaviour between Node.js versions

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I try to learn how to use the debugger in VS Code for my Node.js application. I've found quite a few posts here and there about this, but I can't manage to have things work smoothly.

The end goal is to have a Typescript project with Babel 7 handling the compilation. And I want it to run on the latest version of Node.js (11.0.0).

I had average results so far, but I found a very good [article](https://medium.com/@drcallaway/debugging-es6-in-visual-studio-code-4444db797954) on Medium which presents exactly what I want to do, except that it doesn't have typescript and it runs on Babel 6. But I figure that it is a great starting point to learn, so I try to reproduce it ... and I find that it doesn't behave the same way depending on the version of Node.js that I am running.
Here is what I do...

Running Node.js 8.12.0 and VS Code 1.28, I create a new project folder and I run the commands `npm init -y` and `npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-es2015`.
I update my package.json as follows:

```
// package.json
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"
},
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

I then create 2 javascript files containing my code:

```
// src/app.js
import {add, multiply} from './math';
const num1 = 5, num2 = 10;    // breakpoint on this line
console.log('Add: ', add(num1, num2));
console.log('Multiply: ', multiply(num1, num2));

// src/math.js
export function add(num1, num2) {
  return num1 + num2;    // breakpoint on this line
}
export function multiply(num1, num2) {
  return num1 * num2;    // breakpoint on this line
}
```

I update the package.json file with the following script

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "compile": "babel src --out-dir .compiled --source-maps --watch"
},
```

When I run `npm run compile`, 4 files are created in the `./.compile/` folder, 2 of which are .map files.

Until now, everything goes fine. I then proceed with configuring the debugger in VS Code.
I create a `.vscode/launch.json` file and I edit it as follows:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch App.js",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/app.js",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/.compiled/**/*.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

After placing 3 breakpoints (see my comments in the code above) in my code, I run the debugger which stops on all 3 breakpoints.
Happy with my results, I update Node.js to v9.11.2. I run the debugger again, and it performs the same. Good.

Then, I update Node.js v10.13.0. Without modifying anything in VS Code or in my code, I run the debugger again. This time, only the breakpoint in `src/app.js` is considered. The 2 breakpoints in `src/math.js` are ignored. Why?

When updating Node.js to v11.0.0, I make the same observation.

I figure that something has changed in the way Node.js performs the debugging when they updated from v9.x.x to v10.x.x, but I can't find what.
I believe that I just need to configure launch.json a bit differently, and I have tried many things without success. My current launch.json is the following:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch App.js",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/app.js",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/.compiled/**/*.js"
      ],
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "protocol": "inspector"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea why it doesn't work with Node v10.x and above, and how I can fix this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you had a look here already? https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/23693

Comment: The problem that they describe on your link is not the same, but looks very similar and the issues might be related. I just tried with Node.js v10.11.0, and it works as intended.